# ReferenceError: Socket is not defined .....while creating a NODE SERVER using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, visual-web-developer, socket.io-1.0

I was creating a **Chat Application** using Node JS where i have been using Socket.Io library to build a two way connection between the client and the web server.

**Here is my code (Creating Node Server):**

```
// Node Server that will handle Socket io connections

const io = require('socket.io')(3000)            // Requiring the socket io Library

const users = {};

io.on("connections", (socket) => {
    socket.on("new-user-joined", (name) => {
        users[socket.id] = name;    
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined", name)
    });
});

socket.on('send', message =>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('recieve', {message: message, name: users[socket.id]});
});
```

My node server stop and display this error :

***Problem:***

```
    PS C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\Desktop\complete web development bootcamp\Chat Application\Node Server> nodemon .\index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`
C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\Desktop\complete web development bootcamp\Chat Application\Node Server\index.js:14
socket.on('send', message =>{
^

ReferenceError: socket is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\Desktop\complete web development bootcamp\Chat Application\Node Server\index.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: There is no `socket` in that scope, that much is true. The `socket.on('send', ...` bit should probably be within that `io.on("...")` handler, don't you think?

Comment: ya thanks i did a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to variable socket where you wrote `socket.on('send', ...` is simply out of scope where the `socket` itself is a defined variable. This variable only defined in the function that you give as second argument to the `io.on` call and should be referenced there normally. And that function takes it as an argument named `socket` by the way.

So you should carry your `socket.on` code block inside that function:

```
io.on("connections", (socket) => {
    socket.on("new-user-joined", (name) => {
        users[socket.id] = name;    
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined", name)
    });
    socket.on('send', message => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('recieve', {message: message, name: users[socket.id]});
    });
});
```

just like you do for the `socket.on('new-user-joined', ...)`

Comment: how do we export "socket" globally so that we can emit anywhere within our code?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. One could assign socket passed to `io` `connection` event handler function in a global variable inside of that function. However, I feel you do not need this. However, technically a better approach could be  emitting a custom event inside the `connection` event handler at and listening that event by another custom event emitter/target defined in the scope you prefer.